# Join two datasets according to timestamp and combine their descriptor variables

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two dataframe like these sample data (df1 and df2). I need to join two dataset to take two dataframe df1 and df2, and combine their descriptor variables(motion) so whenever there is a change in any state a new record is created on df1:

The aim here is add motion status variable to each viewing interval,I would like to have this result:

```
date    id  viewing_start   viewing_end motion
2019-01-01  18404885    155900  155959  ON
2019-01-01  18404885    160400  160859  ON
2019-01-01  18404885    170100  170259  ON
2019-01-01  18404885    170400  170459  ON
2019-01-01  18404885    170500  171259  ON
2019-01-08  18404885    201100  201859  idle
```

my dataset ( viweing_start, viewing_end, start_time and end_time are originally H:M:S format (time)

```
   df1 <- data.frame(
  date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01",
           "2019-01-01", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08",
           "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08",
           "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08",
           "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08"),
  id = c(18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885,
         18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885,
         18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885,
         18404885, 18404885, 18404885),
  viewing_start = c(155900, 160400, 170100, 170400, 170500, 201100, 202000,
                    203300, 203700, 204100, 204900, 205200, 205600, 210000,
                    210200, 210800, 211700, 212400, 212900),
  viewing_end = c(155959, 160859, 170259, 170459, 171259, 201859, 202159,
                  203459, 203859, 204759, 204959, 205259, 205659, 210059,
                  210659, 211659, 211859, 212759, 220259)
) %>% 
  mutate(viewing_start = anytime::anytime(paste0(date," ", viewing_start), tz = "CET"),
         viewing_end = anytime::anytime(paste0(date," ", viewing_end) , tz = "CET")) 


df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  id = c(18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885,
                         18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885, 18404885),
                  date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01",
                           "2019-01-01", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08",
                           "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08"),
                  start_time = c("030000", "033715", "080615", "225215", "250000",
                                 "030000", "033700", "082915", "204100", "205100",
                                 "220315"),
                  end_time = c("033715", "080615", "225215", "250000", "030000",
                               "033700", "082915", "204100", "205100", "220315",
                               "241245"),
                  motion = c("idle", "idle", "ON", "idle", "idle", "idle", "idle", "ON",
                             "WARN", "OFF", "ON")) %>% 
  mutate( start_time = paste0(date," ", as.character(start_time)),
          end_time = paste0(date," ", as.character(end_time))) %>% 
mutate(start_time = anytime::anytime(start_time),
       end_time = anytime::anytime(end_time))
```

Comment: I guess you want to join the sets according to start_time and viewing_start right? Then these to should be in the same format for a join.

Comment: Yes, sort of. Thats the issue. since time in my dataset is start from 03:00:00 until 26:00:00 (3 am until 3 am next day) . I haven't find any function to handle this strange time format

Comment: it's not clear how you get that result. can you explain a bit more? what do start_time and viewing_start have to do with each other? how do you know which entry to match to which?

Comment: @ArthurYip my aim here is to add the motion column from df2 into df1 datatable. let's say for each record in df1 , viewing_time/viewing_end interval occurred when df2 reports what motion status ---"ON", "idle" or "OFF --- according to the correspondent time span interval

Comment: What if there's a different status at viewing_start and at viewing_end time? Hard to compare intervals because then there could be multiple statuses per viewing interval. Maybe you only care about status at viewing_start or viewing_end? Then it shouldn't be too difficult to match.

Comment: you'll probably also want to fix the date/time issue that you mentioned. are you saying a row in df2 saying 2019-01-01 26:00 should actually be 2019-01-02 02:00 ?

Comment: @ArthurYip I fixed the date/time issue by using anytime::anytime package (the sample dataset is updated). Hmm, I see your point so I was thinking if there is a way  whenever there is a change in  statuses per viewing interval  a new record is created on df1? I tried rolling join but it didnot work as well

Comment: You could try fuzzy_join and interval_join in the fuzzyjoin package. this will allow you to join data frames with inexact matches. You can't use regular joins because R doesn't know which row from df2 you want for each df1.